# How to connect to database which in VM at the same machine without network cable?

Tags: oracle, virtual-machine

I have a VM at my Laptop and I installed Oracle database on it.. I need to access this database from the main windows (host) without connect a network cable..
I am using Oracle VM software.
I am using bridge option in VM network setting.. I cant access to VM database if the network cable not connected.
how I can do it?

thanks

Comment: add a port forward from local port X to virtual machine port 1521

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your host and VM to communicate without a physical network, you'll need to create a [host-only network](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly) and set up your VM to use that.

[This guide walks through it in detail](https://cs4118.github.io/dev-guides/host-only-network.html), but the basic steps are:

1. In VirtualBox Manager, go to Tools > Network, and create (or use existing) **virtual host-only network**, with DHCP server enabled.
2. Turn your VM off. Go to Settings > Network and create a new host-only adapter, choosing the network from step 1.
3. Turn your VM on, and find its IP address.
4. Connect to the VM from the host

Comment: it is working now.. thank you very much